# Airflow Web do not use auto-refresh and keeps on loading

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x

I deployed airflow on kubernetes and upload a sample DAG file using git sync.
But DAGs in web ui tried to load but nothing is shown.

1. In the image below, "Runs" and "Recent Tasks" show the loading mark but never load.
   [image]
2. When I go to the grid view, I always see the message "Auto-refresh Error" and the auto-refresh toggle is disabled.
   [image]
3. The weird thing is that other views(like graph, calendar, ...) load normally.
   [image]

I cannot find any errors in web log:

```
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:41 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "kube-probe/1.24"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /dags/helloWorld/grid?root= HTTP/1.1" 200 10367 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/graph" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/select2/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/font-awesome.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/materialIcons.f9559e4953177b8b9a4a.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/main.4326607f6e6a434600a7.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/loadingDots.5da42d00b5455806e709.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/flags/flags16.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/flash.eb8d441e4edaecf40ce7.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/switch.0e45299d29df3c0c8282.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/ab.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/js/ab_filters.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/dist/airflowDefaultTheme.a27149057fd893ed3d09.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/js/jquery-latest.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/js/ab_actions.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:48 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:51 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "kube-probe/1.24"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:33:51 +0000] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 141 "-" "kube-probe/1.24"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /dags/helloWorld/grid?root= HTTP/1.1" 200 10371 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/materialIcons.f9559e4953177b8b9a4a.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/flash.eb8d441e4edaecf40ce7.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/select2/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/js/ab.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/ab.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/css/flags/flags16.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/appbuilder/js/ab_actions.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/main.4326607f6e6a434600a7.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/loadingDots.5da42d00b5455806e709.css HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/grid.34b3cc89471d1bec00f0.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
x.x.x.x - - [05/Jul/2023:08:34:00 +0000] "GET /static/dist/dag.7b6f1c9b60adf3d244ac.js HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://my-cluster/http:airflow-web:8080/proxy/dags/helloWorld/grid?root=" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Where can I find hints?